# Order of JPA entities at entity level

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity which has a 1:n relationship to itself:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "\"group\"")
 class Group {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      Integer id;

      @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parentGroup")
      @JoinTable(
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parentgroup_id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false)}
      )
      @OrderColumn
      List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
 }
```

If I use the JPA query

```
 select g from Group g where g.id = ?
```

I get an ordered list of child groups.

How can I get an ordered list of parent groups, so that the following query returns an ordered list of all Groups which do not have a parent group?

```
 select g from Group g where g.parentGroup is null
```

I understand that its not possible to use JPA for this.

I don't want to break the ordering of my current child groups, which would happen in case I decide to invent a new column, which I fill myself.

I want to order parent groups, possibly using the already existing column "groups_order" which is generated for the child groups by JPA.

Is there a lean solution to this problem?

I am using JPA 2 with EclipseLink and Spring Data JPA, if that matters.

Comment: you can use ORDER BY g.someProp in your second query

Comment: But that would include manual ordering using a custom property, which I don't want because it differs from the way we order child groups.

Comment: well, how is the list supposed to be ordered if there is no oredering info provided? You either need to give JPA something to order by, or sort the result list 'manually'.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I (hopefully) clarified my requirements.

Comment: The order field used for the parent to child relation is stores in the join table, and anyway, because parentGroup is null, these groups don't have an ordering anyway.  Just use the order by on the groups id field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way: replace your `@OrderColumn` with `@OrderBy("groupsOrder")`, after generating the `groups_order` column:

```
@Column(name="groups_order") 
private int groupsOrder;//it may be not necessarily to expose this field within a public getter
```

Of course when retrieving the Parent Groups, you need to sort as kostja explained:

```
 SELECT g FROM Group WHERE g.parentGroup is null ORDER BY g.groupsOrder
```